# Differential equation for the logistic map

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From the [Wikipedia article on the logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) I find the following definition as a recurrence relation:

$$x_{n+1} = rx_n(1 - x_n) \tag{1} $$

Then, [in another article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Example), I see how to derive from this the closely related logistic function. This begins by rewriting the recurrence in $(1)$ as a differential equation:

$$x' = rx(1 - x) \tag{2} $$

And the solution to $(2)$ is the function

$$x(t) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-rt}} \tag{3} $$

When I [compare the graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hm6z.png) of $(1)$ and $(3)$ I see that they are not the same, and this does not appear to be a problem with the scaling of the graph.

Why does evaluating $(3)$ at $n$ not give me $x_n$ (the value of $x$ after $n$ iterations) in $(1)$? Is solving the recurrence different to solving it's differential equation?

Comment: Yes, the recurrence and the differential equation are very different.

Comment: For one thing, the left side in (1) is $x_{n+1}$, the **value** of the population at the next iteration, while the left side in (2) is $x'(t)$, the **rate of change** of the population at time $t$.

Comment: Yes, and the solution to (2) gives the *value* of the population at time $t$. It is these functions (and graphs) I am comparing.

Comment: How exactly did you plot those and for what value of r

Answer (score 1):

If you want a discrete approximation to the solution of the differential equation (2), you could take (the Euler approximation with step size $h$)

$$x_{n+1} = x_n + h r x_n (1 - x_n)$$

This can be written as a scaled version of (1):

$$ y_{n+1} = (1 + hr) y_n (1 - y_n) $$

where $x_n = y_n (1+hr)/(hr)$.

Comment: Thanks, but really I want a continuous approximation of equation (1). I thought this is what I was getting with (3).

Comment: Just reverse the steps to go from the $y$ equation to the $x$ differential equation.

Comment: Of course, there's no hope of a good approximation unless (1) is in the region of parameter space where the nonzero fixed point is stable.

Answer (score 0):

The *delay logistic equation* shows a similar behavior like the logistic map up to the first bifurcation : http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DelayLogisticEquation/

Higher number of cycles can be achieved with *multiple delays*  :

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.7022.pdf - Stability and Hopf Bifurcation
  Analysis of the Delay Logistic Equation
- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319977097_Unbounded_and_blow-up_solutions_for_a_delay_logistic_equation_with_positive_feedback